# How can I get std::stringsteam to line up decimal places on floating point numbers?

Tags: c++, floating-point, string-formatting, stringstream, text-alignment

In C++, I have some code like this:

```
float hits = 10.12;
float mins = 2.19;
std::ostringstream ss;

ss.precision(2);

ss << std::fixed << hits << "%\n"
   << std::fixed << mins << "%";

std::cout << ss.str();
```

Which is giving me this output:

```
10.12%
2.19%
```

Whereas, instead I would like the decimal places to align:

```
10.12%
 2.19%
```

Is there a way to pad with spaces before the decimal to have a fixed width of space for two digits before the decimal place?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: @Peter - this stuff is non-intuitive, as with a lot of `iostreams` bells and whistles.  I think this is a well-presented question and not worthy of RTFM response.

Comment: @Peter Wood: What documentation? Or is your comment just a nice RTFM?

Comment: Okay, maybe it was a little harsh. But in the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) for fomatting and format flags, `precision` is next to `width`, and a little before `fixed` is `right`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `width` to set the column size and then [std::right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyezay2f.aspx) to justify the output.

Comment: ..and be careful to set the width wide enough so no number will overflow the bounds

Comment: Or use `std::fill` to fill spaces ahead.

Answer (score 3):

There are `setw()` and `setprecision()` to determine the output-width and the precision for floating-point-values. So you should be able to use it like

```
ss << setw(8) << hits << "%\n"; ...
```

Look [here](http://www.gibson.vero-beach.fl.us/classes/cop2000/output_formatting.html) for reference.

Comment: This `setw()` also work fine with 'std::fill()'. I upvote this answer.